# Read file in java linux?

Tags: java

```
File f = new File("~/NetBeansProjects/ChatApp/src/chatapp/Server.java");

if(f.exists()) {
    System.out.println("File exist");
}
```

`cat ~/NetBeansProjects/ChatApp/src/chatapp/Server.java`,  prints the content of the file.

But the above program doesn't print "File exist".

Comment: are you using the same user accounts ??

Comment: I'm not sure `File` knows what `~` is

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `~` is resolved by the shell, whereas Java do not resolve it. Try something like this:

```
File f = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "NetBeansProjects/ChatApp/src/chatapp/Server.java");
```

Answer (score 1):

The "home" wildcard (`~`) cannot be resolved in the JVM. You need to load that property via the [Java API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html):

```
File f = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "NetBeansProjects/ChatApp/src/chatapp/Server.java");

if(f.exists()) {
    System.out.println("File exist");
}
```